# getting value inside a delegate method not out side of that method

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

    //[_mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = _mapview.centerCoordinate;
    double lat = center.latitude;
    double lng = center.longitude;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lat];
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lng];
    _newlat = str;
    _newlong=str1;

    NSLog(@"%@ %@",_newlat,_newlong);
}
```

I am getting long lat value in side this but not out side of this delegate method.  I want this value in previous class when I pop over to previous class.

I did with declaring delegate but every time i drag the map it gets called and I am not getting value in previous class.

Comment: Where are _newlat and long declared inside the delated class or the main class?

Comment: this is declared in side the main class this in .h file of this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need to set observer object which is observing coordinates and is notified when new coordinates come.

In your CLLocationManagerDelegate class .m

```
-(void) setLocationObserver:(id) observer
{
   self.locationObserver = observer
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

    //[_mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = _mapview.centerCoordinate;
    double lat = center.latitude;
    double lng = center.longitude;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lat];
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lng];
    _newlat = str;
    _newlong=str1;

    if ([self.locationObserver respondsToSelector:@selector(setNewCoords:)
        [self.locationObserver setNewCoords:center];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@",_newlat,_newlong);
}
```

In your previous class .m:

```
-(void)-(void) setNewCoords:(CLLocationCoordinate2D*) location
{
    self.myLocation = location;
    [self doSeomethingWithNewLocation]; // if you wish
}

-(void) doSomethingWithNewLocation
{
    NSString * _newlat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.myLocation.latitude];
    NSString * _newlong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.myLocation.longitude];
}
```

Rough example, but may help.

Comment: sorry it is not working could you tell me how i get _newlat _newlong out side this method

Comment: Here you are, hope it helps. If you have any problem, please be more specific what is not working so we can figure it out.

Comment: if ([self.locationObserver respondsToSelector:@selector(setNewCoords:)
        [self.locationObserver setNewCoords:center]; this line showing error .

Comment: Please be specific. What kind of error? What is the error message?